# Using Facebook Graph API I can access the JSOD for my album but not through an api call via PHP SDK

Tags: php, oauth, facebook-graph-api

My problem is this.
I can access the JSOD, for any browsers, regardless of cookies/cache using the graph API and will be granted permission. But when I try to use it with php sdk, it won't show unless I'm logged in.

NOTE:

The user it's access has been oAuth'd with 'offline_access'.

***This works from anywhere, anytime, regardless of me being logged in or not.***

```
https://graph.facebook.com/113401955056/photos?access_token=195481353795312|21c8aad906641dc6f0894861-509590056|IEyCHjWm-3XFpX__eCtv0OMZUisectrezz
```

***This doesn't work unless I'm already logged into Facebook.***

```
<?php
require_once ('../lib/facebook.php');

$app_id = '195481353795312';
$app_secret = 'secretzz';
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
  'appId'  => $app_id,
  'secret' => $app_secret,
  'cookie' => true,
));

  $photos = $facebook->api("/113401955056/photos?access_token=195481353795312|21c8aad906641dc6f0894861-509590056|IEyCHjWm-3XFpX__eCtv0OMZUisecretz");

  foreach($photos['data'] as $photo)
  {
    echo '<figure class="thumbnail">
    <a href="'.$photo['source'].'">
    <img src="'.$photo['picture'].'" />
    </a>
    <figcaption class="thumb_title">'.$photo['name'].'</figcaption>
    <!-- end of thumb -->
    </figure><!-- end of figure -->
    ';
  }
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as i know, you actually need the user token for off-line_access

```
$session = $facebook->getSession();

if ($session) {
    // you need to store the $session['access_token']; 
}
```

After that, you can get the user data in an off-line manner :

```
$token =  array(

    'access_token' => 'TOKEN HERE'

);

$userdata = $facebook->api('/me', 'GET', $token);
```

Here's the whole article about it - http://eagerfish.eu/using-facebook-off-line-access-to-post-on-users-wall/
I hope it helps.

Comment: "The user it's access has been oAuth'd with 'offline_access'." And the offline_access permission changes only the time the token is valid. So it shouldnt change anything as long a his current token is valid.

Comment: Yes but he is not making the API call correctly in my opinion.

Comment: This is only used for grabbing the session and the access token. After that it's stored. Instead of storing it in the database, I'm hardcoding it into the php, since I'm going to be the only user of my app.

Comment: Ahh! You're answer was correct but it was a bit confusing the way you worded it. This is what fixed my problem: $photos = $facebook->api("/113401955056/photos", array('access_token' => '195481353795312|21c8aad906641dc6f0894861-509590056|IEyCHjWm-3XFpX__eCtv0OMZUisecretz'));

Comment: I'm glad i helped. Best of luck with that Facebook stuff. Without good documentation can be very frustrating.